# multiple values in option tag

Tags: c#, html, sql

I have a drop-down list like

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        <span>Status:</span>
                        <select name="status" id="status">
                            <option value = ''>Please select</option>
                            <option value="Passed">Cleared</option>
                            <option value="Failed">Redo</option>
                            <option value="Improvent" value ="second level improvement" value="third level improvement">Pending</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

I am fetching data from SQL using asp.net webmethod. How can I have multiple values inside option tag? In my database, if I have either improvement or second level improvement or third level improvement I should display as pending. In database value, if the value is passed I was able to display cleared and if the value is failed I was able to display Redo. I am not sure how to have multiple values in option tag. If it can be done on the server side can anyone explain how can i do with asp.net?

Comment: So if you select it from the dropdown, how is it supposed to know what value of the 2 you mean? Or is it readOnly?

Comment: If I get what you're asking you could put something like (value = "Value1 Value2").  You would split the result.  Could you rephrase the question so it's more clear?